# Insertions throws "Document String has change vector B:44-FJLAj, but Put was called with expecting new document" from RavenDB using .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, .net-6.0, ravendb5

Below **error** is thrown while **inserting** a new record in RavendBD using .NET6.

Is it because the same **id already exists** in the RavenDB or there is any other things that need to be taken care explicitly?

```
{
  "message": "Document String has change vector B:44-FJLAj+/nuk+XMaK239q93w, C:45- 
  g4fL0AQJvkqqH0a3fl/0xw, A:63-it/GlSrkfkKOWb/7tSvx1A, but Put was called with expecting 
  new document. Optimistic concurrency violation, transaction will be aborted.",
  "errorList": [],
  "isSuccess": false
}
```

Please let me know if more stuffs is required to support the question.

Comment: Seems that the id already exists, e.g. see this test where such error is thrown:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/58b5930e84fcb8c2a3bb41e93d05f99b6ac69d3b/test/SlowTests/Issues/RavenDB_9576.cs#L34